# Why would Maven enforcer restrict to Java 1.6?

Tags: java, maven

When I run `mvn test` on my project, I get a JDK version error.

Here's the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< net.rorynolan:Detrendr >-----------------------
[INFO] Building Detrendr 0.0.0.9003-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-rules) @ Detrendr ---
[INFO] Adding ignorable dependency: null:jcodings:null
[INFO]   Adding ignore: org/jcodings/*
[INFO] Adding ignorable dependency: null:jnr-constants:null
[INFO]   Adding ignore: com/kenai/constantine/*
...
[INFO] Adding ignorable dependency: com.sun:tools:null
[INFO]   Adding ignore: *
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.6 yet org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.1:test contains org/junit/platform/commons/JUnitException.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.6 yet org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.3.1:test contains org/junit/jupiter/api/AssertArrayEquals.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.6 yet org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.3.1:test contains org/junit/jupiter/engine/Constants.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.6 yet org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.1:test contains org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[WARNING] Rule 5: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceBytecodeVersion failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.3.1
Found Banned Dependency: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.3.1
Found Banned Dependency: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.3.1
Found Banned Dependency: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.3.1
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My `pom.xml` is at https://github.com/rorynolan/ij_detrendr/blob/master/pom.xml.

There's a clue in `mvn help:effective-pom`

where I can see

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  ...
  <rules>
    ...  
    <enforceBytecodeVersion>
      <maxJdkVersion>1.6</maxJdkVersion>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>com.headius:invokebinder</exclude>
          <exclude>com.sun:tools</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </enforceBytecodeVersion>
      <banCircularDependencies />
    </rules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But that's all I've got. I've tried adding the maven enforcer plugin explicitly to my own `pom.xml` but to no avail.

Comment: If you see the entry with maven-enforcer in your effective pom that means it is inherited from your parent pom which limits to JDK 6...So the question is why does the parent limit to 1.6 ? I suppose there is a reason for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project [pom](https://github.com/rorynolan/ij_detrendr/blob/master/pom.xml) is parented by: [net.imagej:pom-imagej:13.2.0](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/imagej/pom-imagej/13.2.0/pom-imagej-13.2.0.pom) which is parented by [org.scijava:pom-scijava:8.4.0](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scijava/pom-scijava/8.4.0/pom-scijava-8.4.0.pom) which contains the following excerpts relating to Java version:

```
<scijava.jvm.version>1.6</scijava.jvm.version>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <!-- Require the Java 6 platform. -->
  <configuration>
    <source>${scijava.jvm.version}</source>
    <target>${scijava.jvm.version}</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
  <enforceBytecodeVersion>
    <maxJdkVersion>${scijava.jvm.version}</maxJdkVersion>
    ...
  </enforceBytecodeVersion>
</plugin>
```

So, the enforcer rule and its insistence on Java 1.6 is being inherited via your project's parentage.

This restriction to Java 1.6 conflicts with the JUnit5 libraries which were compiled to Java 1.8.

You *could* perhaps overide the enforcer plugin in your own POM (see references to `combine.self="override"` in [the Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)) but the fact that your module's grandparent (`org.scijava:pom-scijava:8.4.0`) explicitly states that it expects to run on Java 1.6 strongly suggests that any such override will cause issues.

I think the wiser course would be one of the following:

- Downgrade from Junit5 to a version of Junit4 which is compatible with Java 1.6
- Upgrade the version of your parent (`net.imagej:pom-imagej:13.2.0`) to one which is compatible with Java 8, note: `net.imagej:pom-imagej:13.2.0` is 3 years old so you might find that upgrading to the latest version makes this problem disappear.